# Show that the open interval (a, b) is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have to show that an open interval in the form $(a,b)$, where $a,b \in {\mathbb R}$ and  $a < b$ is Lebesgue measurable. 
I think I'm supposed to show, that the subset $(a,b)$ is Lebesgue measurable, if and only if:

$$m(A) = m(A ∩ S) + m(A ∩ S^c)$$

where $S \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ and $S^c$ is the complement of $S$. 
But how do I actually prove that the open interval $(a,b)$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: What is your definition of being measurable? Are you using outer measure?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, I think OP is using the [Carathéodory's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion) as definition.

Comment: But at lest OP should precise what is $A$ and $S$ as he is looking to prove the measurability of $(a,b)$.

Comment: The purpose of the exercise is to proove that any interval in ℝ is Lebesgue measurable by showing that any open interval  in the form (a,b) is Lebesgue measurable. S in this exercise is the subset (a,b) and A is any S⊆ℝn. We use the outer measure as a definition of being measurable.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are considering sets in $\mathbb R.\ $ Let $A\in \mathcal P (\mathbb R),\ I=(a,b)$ and $\ \epsilon>0.\ $ For convenience, denote both the outer measure and length of intervals by $|\cdot|.$

There is a sequence $(I_n)$ of intervals such that $\bigcup I_n\supseteq A$ and $\sum |I_n|<|A|+\epsilon.\ $ Set $J_n=I\cap I_n;\ J_n'=I^c\cap I_n.\ $ Some of these may be empty, but that's ok.

Then,

$|I_n|=|J_n|+|J_n'|,\ A \cap I \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} J_n,\ A \cap I^c \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} J'_n,\ $ and these facts imply that $|A\cap I|+|A\cap I^c|\le |A|+\epsilon.$

Comment: And how does one get equality?

Comment: @mavavilj For any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ you can say that $A = (A \cap I) \cup (A \cap I^c)$. Therefore by countable-subadditivity you have $|A| \leq  |A \cap I| + |A \cap I^c|$.